# Decouple iron-overlay-closed on a paper-dialog

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I want to execute a time consuming operation when one of my paper-dialogs is confirmed. I noticed that when my handler for the paper-dialogs iron-overlay-closed event is called, the dialog is still visible.

How would I execute my operation after the dialog has been visually closed. Is there some recommended kind of decoupling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Async or Debounce methods to delay the operation:

Docs is here: 
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods

Example using Debounce:
[Polymer: Delay value changed execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349795/polymer-delay-value-changed-execution)

Sometimes I'm using custom timeout in this cases:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
         //do something after 300ms
}.bind(this),300);
```